# Google API for Keyword Queries

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have been looking around the internet and looking for an API on the Keyword Queries. What i mean by this is the section on Google Analytics Dashboard that is located at `Acquisition > Search Engine Optimization > Queries`

I also checked on the Webmaster Tool API, but it also does not offer an API Search Keyword Queries.

Is there a Google API that allows me to get those data?

If there is none, can you recommend me any other alternatives.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: There's a Google Analytics API that will let you get almost any stats in your analytics dashboard ?

Comment: @adeneo yeah, but it does not offer search queries :(

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find this myself. Looks like they do not offer it at this time. Here is the list of endpoints - 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets